# Python NameError: global name 'score' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to complete a program that has been set as back to school work, but I've never used Python before so I'm struggling to see where the error lies. Any help would be appreciated, preferably by Thursday as this is when the work is due!

```
#revision platform
def Spelling():
    global test
    global score
    score = 0
print("Welcome to the Spelling test.")
Q1=raw_input("Which spelling is correct:\nChangeable\nChangeble\n")
if Q1=="Changeable":
    print("Correct")
    score +=  1
else:
    print("Incorrect")
Q2=raw_input("Which spelling is correct:\nThreshhold\nThreshold\n")
if Q2=="Threshold":
    print("Correct")
    score += 1
else:
    print("Incorrect")
Q3=raw_input("Which spelling is correct:\nScent\nSent\nCent\n")
if Q3=="Scent" or Q3=="Sent" or Q3=="Cent":
    print("Trick Question they were all right!")
    score += 1
    print("Your score is:" ,score)
else:
    print("Incorrect")
    print("Your score is:",score)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It looks like your indentation is off.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you be more specific with what the issue is? It would be helpful if you could add the traceback as well

Comment: The problem is indentation. But why do you declare those variables as global?

Comment: in python you don't need to declare variables before use. Just remove `def Spelling()`, the two `global` statements and make sure `score=0` isn't indented and this should work.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 10, in <module>
NameError: global name 'score' is not defined

Comment: Thank you, removing my global variables and removing the indent on my score worked! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
#revision platform
def Spelling():
    score = 0
    print("Welcome to the Spelling test.")
    Q1=raw_input("Which spelling is correct:\nChangeable\nChangeble\n")
    if Q1=="Changeable":
        print("Correct")
        score +=  1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
    Q2=raw_input("Which spelling is correct:\nThreshhold\nThreshold\n")
    if Q2=="Threshold":
        print("Correct")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
    Q3=raw_input("Which spelling is correct:\nScent\nSent\nCent\n")
    if Q3=="Scent" or Q3=="Sent" or Q3=="Cent":
        print("Trick Question they were all right!")
        score += 1
        print("Your score is:" ,score)
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        print("Your score is:",score)
```

Just call Spelling() function then your program will work